# contextual type cannot be used with array literal Swift 3 colors array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having issues with my colors when trying to create an array in Swift 3. My code for the code like so:

```
//// Color Declarations
let gradientColor = UIColor(red: 0.859, green: 0.948, blue: 0.308, alpha: 1.000)
let gradientColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.979, green: 0.677, blue: 0.267, alpha: 1.000)
let colors = [gradientColor.CGColor, gradientColor.blendedColorWithFraction(0.5, ofColor: gradientColor2).CGColor, gradientColor2.CGColor] as CFArray
//// Gradient Declarations
let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors, [0, 0.5, 1])!
```

I get the error `contextual type cannot be used with array literal`. Googled around for help on this and it said to cast the colors array to a `CFArray` which I have done. However I am still seeing this error, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is in `blendedColorWithFraction`, its for `NSColor`, not `UIColor`, and its for OSX

Comment: There's the real answer to his question! I was wondering what `blendedColorWithFraction` was...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious if you're actually using swift version 3 because you're using 2.x APIs (`.CGColor` instead of `.cgColor`, `CGGradientCreateWithColors` instead of `CGGradient`'s init), but anyway in swift 3:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let gradientColor = UIColor(red: 0.859, green: 0.948, blue: 0.308, alpha: 1.000)
let gradientColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.979, green: 0.677, blue: 0.267, alpha: 1.000)

let colors = [gradientColor.cgColor, gradientColor2.cgColor]

let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as CFArray, locations: [0, 0.5, 1])
```

I'm not familiar with `blendedColorWithFraction` so that must be a renamed apple API or some third party thing you're using.

EDIT: `blendedColorWithFraction` is for `NSColor` (@Tj3n mentioned in a comment), which is your "actual" problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was using an old version of Paintcode hence the older Swift code in there.